# tophline/multirow is not recognize in latex

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am not able to figureout why this is not working

```
\begin{table*}
    \caption{Pearson correlation between daily data.}
    \label{tab:corr}
    \begin{tabular}{l l c c}
        \tophline
        \multirow{2}{0.23cm}{S.N.} & &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Pearson correlation coefficient(r)} \\
        \cline{3-4} & MODIS SDS & normal & dry \\
        %\hhline{~--}
        \middlehline
        1 &\texttt{A}        & 0.68 & 0.85 \\  
        2 &\texttt{B}        & 0.68 & 0.85 \\
        3 &\texttt{C}        & 0.57 & 0.76 \\
        4 &\texttt{D}        & 0.75 & 0.87 \\
        \bottomhline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you loaded the packages booktabs and multirow?

Comment: Where are the `\tophline`, &c., defined?

Comment: @Zarko, still not working. I suppose to create this table without using any extra packages

Comment: And you're also supposed to reinvent the wheel? Roast coffee?

Comment: without see minimal working example (a small complete document with your table, which will demonstrate your problem) we can only guessing what you really doing. in my test after correcting your `\tophline` to `\toprule`, `\midhline` to `\midrule` and `bottomhline` to `\bottomrule` and add `booktabs` packagee (sorry for error in my comment, i will remove it) all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

for changes in code which i made in the mwe below compare codes your any my table (differences are indicated by `% <---`):

```
\documentclass{article}         % <---
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Pearson correlation between daily data.}
\label{tab:corr}
\centering                      % <---
\begin{tabular}{l c *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7em}}}  % <---
    \toprule                    % <---
\multirow{2.2}*{S.N.}           % <---
    & \multirow{2.2}{4em}{\centering  MODIS\\ SDS}  % <---
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Pearson correlation coefficient (r)} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}              % <---
    &           & normal    & dry   \\
    \midrule
1   &\texttt{A} & 0.68      & 0.85 \\
2   &\texttt{B} & 0.68      & 0.85 \\
3   &\texttt{C} & 0.57      & 0.76 \\
4   &\texttt{D} & 0.75      & 0.87 \\
    \bottomrule                 % <---
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```